# « C'est un roi » ou « c'est le roi » ? Quel article devrais-je utiliser et pourquoi ?

Tags: grammaire, usage, articles

Salut,
J'ai un problème à propos de l'utilisation des articles, ne sachant pas quand je dois choisir le défini ou l'indéfini.

Pouvez-vous m'expliquer quelle est la différence entre    *C'est un roi* et  *C'est le roi* ?

Comment: Bienvenue sur FL. Les deux étant possibles il faut que tu donnes le contexte pour savoir ce qui vient.

Comment: Je voulais écrire pour savoir ce qui **convient** !

Comment: Remplacer l'ancien monarque par nos récents dirigeants : Si l'on parle de Charles de Gaulle  « C'est un président de la République Française ? — Oui du siècle passé » ; « C'est le président de la république qui était au pouvoir en 1968 ? — Oui, lui et pas un autre. »

Comment: Il me semble qu'on ne devrait pas corriger les fautes de français parce que maintenant on a l'impression qu'il s'agit d'un francophone et je vois mal un francophone posé une question pareille.

Comment: @Lambie Ne pas corriger les fautes de français présentes dans les questions ou les réponses me semble une mauvaise idée. Corriger les fautes rend service à celui qui a rédigé en premier puisqu'il peut voir où il s'est trompé, et corriger les fautes permet aux visiteurs du site de ne pas risquer de prendre des formes erronées comme exemples. Ce qu'il faut laisser tel-quel en revanche, ce sont bien sûr les fautes dans les expressions faisant l'objet d'une question puisqu'elle pourrait perdre alors tout son sens. Quant à savoir si un OP est francophone ou pas, souvent ça n'a aucune importance.

Comment: @Lambie D'ailleurs, je regrette beaucoup qu'on ne puisse pas corriger les fautes présentes dans les commentaires, pour les mêmes raisons. Ton *un francophone **posé** une question pareille* pique les yeux, mais un débutant risque de ne rien détecter.

Comment: @jlliagre Sur les autres forums, on ne le fait pas. On corrige les fautes d'orthographe seulement. On devrait mettre les corrections en dessous du texte (moi, je les mets entre parenthèses) pour que la personne les corrige. Ensuite, on peut effacer ces commentaires à propos des corrections. Ouais, poser une question., Si je te disais toutes tes fautes d'anglais, on ne s'en sortirais jamais.

Comment: @Lambie Ce ne sont pas des forums mais des sites de questions-réponses. Les forums, c'est le *chat*. Améliorer les questions est [encouragé](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118239/182055) sur les sites techniques, et c'est [encore plus vrai](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/422/fix-typos-in-learner-question-corriger-les-fautes-dans-une-question-dapprenan) sur les sites dédiés aux langues. D'ailleurs, comme je te l'ai déjà écrit, j'apprécie qu'on corrige mes fautes d'anglais ou de français. Il n'est pas sûr que tout le monde comprenne ta méthode de corrigé entre parenthèses.

Comment: @jlliagre https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5250/when-should-a-question-be-edited-in-these-situations See what Jason says. En corrigeant la question posée ici, on se demand pourquoi un francophone poserait une telle question.

Comment: @Lambie Ce n'est pas ici qu'il faut en discuter. Tu peux donner ton avis dans [meta](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/422/fix-typos-in-learner-question-corriger-les-fautes-dans-une-question-dapprenan) ou y poser une nouvelle question si tu souhaites faire évoluer  la politique de FSE.

Answer (score 1):

**Le** roi est utilisé pour parler d'un roi en particulier. Généralement, ce sera donc le Roi actuel du pays dans lequel la conversation se passe.

Dans la phrase exacte « C'est X roi » la nuance se rapporte à :

> *un* : « Il est roi » : Roi de n'importe quel pays et n'importe quelle ère.

> *le* : « C'est *mon*/*notre* roi » : Roi de ce pays et de cette ère.

On part de l'idée qu'il existe plusieurs rois. Un roi nous dira que la personne fait partie du groupe. Le roi nous indique qu'on sait tous de quel roi il s'agit, comme s'il n'existait qu'un seul roi.

Comment: C'est l'utilisation normale de l'article défini *le* ou de l'article indéfini *un*. Ces considérations pourraient s'appliquer à n'importe quel nom commun, roi ou autre chose.

Comment: oui, tout à fait ! L'exemple de roi est bien pratique pour relever ce concept, puisqu'il y a en a plusieurs mais l'un est toujours plus important selon le contexte.